# Sqlite3 Python Database Locked

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite

I am trying to run an UPDATE query but I keep getting a database locked error. I don't have another thread that is constantly writing, so I don't think that is the problem. I am also closing the connection to the database when ever I am done running the queries in another function. I haven't gotten this error with any of the other queries except for this one.

```
    x = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = x.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE character SET section=? WHERE username=?", ('town','%'+self.username+'%'))
    x.commit()
```

I have tried it sever different ways, such as:

```
    x = sqlite3.connect("database.db")
    c = x.cursor()
    c.execute("UPDATE character SET section='town' WHERE username=?", [self.username])
```

Thanks for your help.
        x.commit()

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python SQLite: database is locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740806/python-sqlite-database-is-locked)

Comment: The only item in the list of the best answer that applied to me was the -journal file being in the directory. I deleted that and still I get the error.

Comment: did you try strace to see what kind of locking fails ?