# OperationalError: database is locked in SQLite3

Tags: python, browser, sqlite, python-3.4

I'm trying to access the history of chrome browser which is a SQLite file. My code was working fine but recently I'm facing this error- 
`sqlite3.OperationalError: database is locked`

Is there any solution?

[image: Error message]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python SQLite: database is locked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740806/python-sqlite-database-is-locked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome locks the database when it is open.
I have closed it and its started working.

Answer (score 1):

Set the timeout parameter:

```
connection = sqlite.connect('name.db', timeout=1)
```

Comment: I'd guess Chrome locks the DB longer than one millisecond.

Comment: That may cause the problem if Chrome locks the DB. Is there any tricks to get away from it?