# SQL Update Command in Python cannot find column and database gets locked

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to increase an integer in a SQL database by one, but I get an error that my database is locked when running the code below:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT score FROM scores WHERE name=?""", (user,)) # works
new_score = cursor.fetchone()[0] + 1 # works

params = (new_score, user) 
cursor.execute("""UPDATE scores SET score=? WHERE name=?""", params) # error here
```

- **new_score** is a variable type int which is increased by one
- **user** is a string that is under the "name" column in the database
- **scores** is the table name
- **score** is a column name in the data base

Thanks for any help!

Comment: `my database is locked` ... what is your actual SQL database?

Comment: sqlite3. I think it is getting locked because the process takes too long based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked/39449185. I'm more unsure why the code above is problematic

Comment: is `name` a key column? How big is your table?

Comment: Yes, name is a key column. My table has two columns (name and score) with about 70 rows

Comment: This is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740806/python-sqlite-database-is-locked. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

If your database is showing it as locked check the running process at that instance and if your process is being blocked by some other process or your process is blocking some other process and unable to find the resources to execute the query.

Generally the solution for dead lock would be to kill any one of those queries. The query that needs to be killed is chosen based on the priority. Based on the database that you are using you can find the respective queries for finding the processes that running at any given point in time.

If you are running the query on MS SQL Server then use the command `EXEC sp_who` this will show the processes list running. Then use the command `EXEC KILL spid_of_the_query` to kill the query. Find the queries that are running at that the instance during which you are running this update query.

Comment: I don't think that this is the issue based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172929/operationalerror-database-is-locked/39449185. I'm mostly unsure why the code labeled # error here is problematic. Thanks for your answer though, and let me know if I'm wrong still

Comment: Run the same update command on the database directly and see if that is working fine or that is also throwing an error.

Comment: Successfully works when I run UPDATE scores SET score = 505 WHERE name = "Swag"

Comment: Try rebuild using command that you are using inside the execute. 
```cursor.execute("""UPDATE scores SET score=? WHERE name=?""", params) ```
change this as follows. 
```update_str = 'UPDATE scores SET score=' + str(new_score) + 'WHERE name=' + user```

Then run the command as follows. 
```cursor.execute(update_str);```

Comment: Database is locked when changing to ``update_str = 'UPDATE scores SET score=' + str(new_score) + ' WHERE name=' + "'" + user + "'"``. When it is just ``update_str = 'UPDATE scores SET score=' + str(new_score) + ' WHERE name=' + user``, I get error "sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: Swag" (Swag being the string for *user*)

Comment: ```update_str = 'UPDATE scores SET score=' + str(new_score) + ' WHERE name="' + user +'"' ```
Use this.

Comment: Still database is locked

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I never closed my connection in the SQLite Browser that I was using. Thanks for all the responses!