# python sqlite3 avoid "database is locked" for multiple processes writing to same db

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sqlite

I have written a script that executes inside docker and writes to an sqlite3 db on host. At a time, there are 8-10 such docker containers writing to the same database (each having their own connection).

In my script, I create an sqlite connection and get a cursor and use it for the lifecycle of the whole program (multiple cur.execute(), con.commit(), con.rollback()).
I initiate the connection with 20 second timeout:

`con = sqlite3.connect('database.db', timeout=20)`

but I still get `sqlite3: database is locked.` errors.
I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3046075/8243797) solution like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        cur.execute(f"...insert into db statement...")
            break
    except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            continue
```

and similarly for `con.commit()` and `con.rollback()` in place of `cur.execute()`.

My question is, is there a better way to do this? I am not checking if the while loop for any of the containers is stuck in infinite loop. I have seen answers creating connection and cursor inside and cursor inside the while loop, does creating a connection lock the database? does cur.execute() lock it or only con.commit()?

Comment: From the SQLite docs: "A good rule of thumb is to avoid using SQLite in situations where the same database will be accessed directly (without an intervening application server) and simultaneously from many computers over a network." In short, it looks like there isn't a better way. Look instead for a DBMS that is designed to be multi-user.

Comment: Would you suggest getting multiple databases? I already have 10 different dbs and split my workflow in 10 parts, i have had socket connection closed issues with mysql (even after increasing max connection limit), (that was wikipedia's software). I want to process ~3 mil tasks as fast as possible, hence i chose sqlite as there is no sockets or server setup.

Comment: Without knowing a good deal more about your project I would not venture a suggestion. I was just pointing out that the SQLite documentation explains at great length and in a lot of detail why multiple connections are not what is designed for. The simplicity of not having to set up a server comes at a price: without a server, client-server functionality is unavailable or, at best, emulated.